# Running time take its too long for adding and finding string from txt

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Sister, Buddy, Programmer, Master.

Based on running time for searching elements, many articles suggest to use HashSet, and List for adding elements.

How to change or improve my code like this:

```
static List<string> getDBList(string DBname)
{
     List<string> listWords = new List<string>();
     string[] files;

     try
     {
         files = Directory.GetFiles(@"dbase/", DBname); 
         foreach (string file in files)
             foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(file))//doubt
                listWords.Add(line.Trim().ToUpperInvariant());
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
         return new List<string> { };
     }

     return listWords;
}
```

Then...

```
//MAIN PROGRAM
string allInput = rtbInput.Text;

List<string> splitString = new List<string>.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', etc...});
List<int> AllIndexes = new List<int>();
HashSet<string> nounList = new HashSet<string>(getDBList("nounList.txt"));//doubt

int startIndexes = 0;

foreach (string s in splitString)
{
    if (s.Trim() != "")
    {
       string word = s.Trim();

       if(!(nounList.Contains(word.ToUpperInvariant())))   //doubt if not found, color it
       { 
               tbTest.Text += word + " ";

               //index to begin color the text
               AllIndexes = WordsIndex(word, startIndexes);

               foreach (int item in AllIndexes) //Coloring all appearance of the word.
               {
                   tbSeeIndex.Text += Convert.ToString(" " + item + " ");

                   rtbInput.Select(item, word.Length);

                   startIndexes = item + word.Length;

                   rtbInput.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
              }

              tbL.Text += Convert.ToString(" " + startIndexes + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

}

It takes too long if i use input form file.

in nounList (90963 word) example :

book
chair
pencil
etc...

I wanna use this code to perform the search based on the string value.
Because I'm not familiar with it.
Let me learn by your example. I'm just amateur. :) :) :)
Thanks a lot. Cheers...

Comment: Why would you need a Dictionary?  This seems to be just a list of strings.  No need for a dictionary here as far as I can tell

Comment: Dear @David L... :)

I need Dictionary for faster searching than List.
Any suggestion?

Comment: @BerryHarahap it's only faster if you're searching by the `key` of the dictionary. What would be the key of a particular line in your files?

Comment: For faster searching, consider using something like a HashSet http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx

Comment: In your case cannot identify unique key for the dictionary. Are you going to perform the search based on the compete string value? or any other michanism.

Comment: Sir @New Developer, hehe. Perhaps I perform the search based on the compete string value, hehe. So is dictionary not suitable?

I should have thought that dictionary faster searching by using key. hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This might help you.

```
static Dictionary<int, string> getDBList(string DBname)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> WordsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    string[] files;

    try
    {
        files = Directory.GetFiles(@"dbase/", DBname);
        foreach (string file in files)
            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(file))
            {
                 string data = line.Trim().ToUpperInvariant();
                 int hash = data.GetHashCode();

                 if(!WordsDictionary.ContainsKey(hash))
                     WordsDictionary.Add(hash, data);                   
            }
        }


    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        return new Dictionary<int, string>();
    } 
    return WordsDictionary;
}

static bool SearchText(string text, Dictionary<int, string> WordsDictionary)
{
    int hash = text.Trim().ToUpperInvariant().GetHashCode();

    if (WordsDictionary.ContainsKey(hash))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: hello.
I changed my code into HashSet, I've modified the question above.
But, the running time is slow. What do you think about my code above (my question now).

Please give me recommendation, :) :) :) Nice, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var nounDictionary = nounList
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

This should create a dictionary for you.  Though, without some sort of useful key, I'm not sure how this would be any "faster".  In addition, I doubt your list-searching speed is the issue here.

EDIT:

An even simpler example would be as follows, where it maps the key as each item in your array and the value as each item to upper.

```
var nounDictionary = nounList.ToDictionary(x => x.ToUpper());
```

Finally, if you want to optimally search your set, use a hashset, as others have pointed out.  Hashset has a constructor that takes IEnumerable, so simply pass in a list of string, since IList implements IEnumerable

```
var set = new HashSet(nounList.ToList());
```

Then, if you want to search your HashSet, you can do something like the following, though this is a question in and of itself.

```
set.Where(x => x.Contains("StringToFind"))
                  .Select(x => x.Split(' ')[0])
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

HashSets are remarkably quick on lookups.  There are some interesting tests here.

http://theburningmonk.com/2011/03/hashset-vs-list-vs-dictionary/

Comment: Sir @David L, this is something i wanna do, but, based on others comment and suggestion, they said that dictionary only faster if doing search by using key, not string value.
They suggest to use HashSet. What do you think Sir David?
Let me learn by your example if HashSet is better, and i wanna change my code. Cheeers. :) :) :)

Comment: @BerryHarahap I've added code for using hashsets as well.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello @Mr David, please give me your advice and suggestion. I've modified the code like my question now. I've tried, and nice, but running time take its too long. Hmm, please see my question above.

Give me suggestion please to make it efficient. :) :) :) Thanks a lot. Cheers